# KnockoutJS bind to div as I'm typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

Is it possible in Knockout to have a "live" binding between a text area and a DIV on the page that updates the DIV every time the content of the textarea changes (character per character)?
I am using a computed field on my view model, but it won't update the DIV unless I tab off the textarea: Is it possible to update it instantly every time a change is made, without having to tab off?

Code

```
function EditModel() {
        this.CommentTextPlain = ko.observable("");

        var self = this;

        this.CommentReady = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.CommentTextPlain().replace(regex, "<BR>");
        });
    }

    function ApplyViewmodel() {
        model = new EditModel();
        ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("mainContainer"));
    }

<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="target" data-bind='html: CommentReady' class="commentEditBox"></div> 

    <textarea data-bind="value: CommentTextPlain" rows="20" cols="62" id="editBoxFull">    </textarea>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `value` binding has a companion option called `valueUpdate` that you can set to include additional events like:

```
data-bind="value: CommentTextPlain, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
```

Answer (score 2):

use `valueUpdate` binding

see **Additional Parameters** section on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

> valueUpdate
>
> If your binding also includes a parameter called valueUpdate, this
>   defines additional browser events KO should use to detect changes
>   besides the change event. The following string values are the most
>   commonly useful choices:
>
> - "keyup" - updates your view model when the user releases a key
> - "keypress" - updates your view model when the user has typed a key.
>     Unlike keyup, this updates repeatedly while the user holds a key down
> - "afterkeydown" - updates your view model as soon as the user begins
>     typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s keydown event
>     and handling the event asynchronously. Of these options,
> - "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to keep your view model
>     updated in real-time.
>
> Of these options, "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to keep your view model updated in real-time

Answer (score 0):

Knockout has a `textInput` binding that achieves immediate model updates without having to use additional parameters to the value binding, while also handling cut-and-paste and text drag events.

Here's the link to the textInput binding documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html.